# Dim myLabelInfo As Office.LabelInfo -- Office.LabellInfo is not found in MS ACCESS VBA

Tags: vba

MS ACCESS VBA - I am building and populating a group of excel spreadsheets from an MS ACCESS database. My company requires spreadsheets to be save with a security label. ( Public, Confidential, etc) I want to set the security label using ACCESS VBA code. However,   "Dim myLabelInfo As Office.LabelInfo" fails as MS ACCESS does not recognize  Office.LabelInfo. Thought it might be in the VBA tools/reference list. Could not find it. The code works in EXCEL VBA but not ACCESS. Any help would be appreciated.

The only work around I have found is to use excel templates pre-saved with the security label. In ACCESS VBA you can open the template spreadsheet, populate the template spreadsheet and save it under a new name. The template security label is passed to the new child spreadsheet. It works but programmed solution would be better.

Answer (score 2):

You probably create the label with a code like this:

```
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Dim label As xxxx  ' What? 
Set label = xlWb.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo
```

Obviously, this code uses Early Binding. If you want to use the correct object type, you will need to add not only the reference to the **Microsoft Excel Object Library**, but also to the **Microsoft Office Object Library**. Then you can declare label as `Office.LabelInfo`

[image]

```
Dim label As Office.LabelInfo
Set label = xlWb.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo
```

Alternative is always to use Late Binding and declare it as Object.

```
Dim label As Object
Set label = xlWb.SensitivityLabel.CreateLabelInfo
```